# Jquery Validation Don't work on Submit if Submit has some Code

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation

I am using MVC Data Anotation with jquery validation for validating my form. It works perfectly on submit but if I write some code on submit click, it doesn't validate it. Why so? Where am I wrong? I am using **jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js** and **jquery.validate.min.js**

I am not getting any kind of error. Just in my case, jquery validation stop working on submit if I put some code on submit click.

**HTML:**

```
<form action="/Login/ChangePassword" id="changePasswordForm" method="post">  <div id="changePasswordDiv" class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-7" for="Current_password_:">Current password :</label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
    <input MaxLength="8" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please enter current password." id="OldPassword" name="OldPassword" placeholder="Enter Your Current Password" type="password" value="" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="OldPassword" data-valmsg-replace="true" id="vOldPassword" style="color:red"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-7" for="New_password_:">New password :</label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
    <input MaxLength="8" MinLength="4" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please enter new password." id="NewPassword" name="NewPassword" placeholder="Enter Your New Password" type="password" value="" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="NewPassword" data-valmsg-replace="true" id="vNewPassword" style="color:red"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-7" for="Confirm_password_:">Confirm password :</label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
    <input MaxLength="8" MinLength="4" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-equalto="The new and confirm passwords should match." data-val-equalto-other="*.NewPassword" data-val-required="Please enter confirm password." id="ConfirmPassword" name="ConfirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" value="" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ConfirmPassword" data-valmsg-replace="true" id="vConfPass" style="color:red"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-7"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
    <input type="submit" id="btnChangePassword" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" value="Save"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions col-right">
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Custom/CustomValidation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
  debugger;
  var validator = $('#changePasswordForm').validate({
    rules: {
    NewPassword: { IsNotEqualString: "#OldPassword" }
    },
    messages: {
    NewPassword: { IsNotEqualString: "New Passowrd can't same as Current Password." }
    }
  });
  });
</script>
```

**CustomValidation.js**

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('IsNotEqualString', function (value, element, param) {  alert(param)
  return this.optional(element) || value.toLowerCase() != $(param).val().toLowerCase();
}, "");
```

[Here is whole code if you want to check.](http://pastie.org/9307457)

Comment: Which validation plugin are you using ? Please share a link.

Comment: What or where get error? You can find the error using the console...

Comment: @MirkoCianfarani no error i am getting just jquery validatation dont work.

Comment: If you're using a validation plugin, then you don't need to write your own validation function.  This is making no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quote OP**:

> *"I am using MVC Data Anotation with jquery validation for validating my form. It works perfectly on submit but if I write some code on submit click, it doesn't validate it. Why so? Where am I wrong? I am using `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` and `jquery.validate.min.js`"*

The jQuery Validation plugin automatically captures the click of the submit button, does its validation, displays errors, and then submits the form if valid.  You're going wrong by putting an `onclick` handler within the submit button.  Your `onclick="return abc()"` simply over-rides the `click` handler built into the jQuery Validation plugin.

> *"I am not getting any kind of error. Just in my case, jquery validation stop working on submit if I put some code on submit click."*

Of course you're not getting an error.  That's because everything is working the way you've programmed it.  Your `onclick="return abc()"` takes over from the jQuery Validation plugin.  It looks like your `abc()` function is manual validation.  Why would you use the jQuery Validation plugin to validate the form and also write your own function to validate the form?  This makes no sense.

[The plugin provides a method for writing your own rules](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/).  Remove the `onclick="return abc()"` from your submit button to let the jQuery Validation plugin operate normally.  Remove the `abc()` function and replace it with a custom rule/method for the jQuery Validation plugin.

Also with jQuery, you should never need to use an event handler within HTML again.  Events can be handled solely within your jQuery code.

```
$('#element').on('click', function() {
    // your code
});
```

This is just an example, because in your case, you don't need a `click` handler function at all.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer, I have modified code as per you suggested. But still facing problem. Custom validation method i have created is still not calling. I don't know where I am wrong. Pls kindly look at my modified code: http://pastie.org/9307457

Comment: @Dhwani,  I took out the `debugger;` line as that makes no sense with what's been shown.  Otherwise, your code, as you've presented it to us, is working:  http://jsfiddle.net/HFqhK/1/

Answer (score 1):

I take the  and comment inside the function.

1. First error when you using Jquery inside the function's Javascript load the library of Jquery. Where you can find on google that share on the [site](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery) or on [Jquery](http://jquery.com/download/)
2. Miss before the `function abc(){` this sentence

   ```
    `$(document).ready(function () {`
   ```

   And add `}` for closing before the closing tag `</script>`
3. Reading the [site of jquery.validate.js](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) this is tested of these version:

`1.6.4, 1.7.2, 1.8.3, 1.9.0` ([link](http://jqueryvalidation.org/#required) ).

Then I suggest of use this [library of Jquery 1.9.0](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js) and [Site](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/15/jquery-1-9-final-jquery-2-0-beta-migrate-final-released/)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
    function abc() {
       // debugger;
        var validated = true;
        var password = $.trim($('#NewPassword').val());
        var oldPassword = $.trim($('#OldPassword').val());
        if (password == oldPassword) {
            $('#vNewPassword').text("New Password can't be same as Old Password.");
            validated = false;
        } else {

            //if password contains both lower and uppercase characters
            if (!password.match(/([a-z].*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*[a-z])/)) {
                validated = false;
            }
            //if it has numbers and characters, increase strength value
            if (!password.match(/([0-9])/)) {
                validated = false;
            }
            //if it has one special character
            //if (password.match(/([!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)){
            //    validated = false;
            //}
        }
        if (validated == false) {
            $('#vNewPassword').text('Password must contain at least one lower and upper case character and one number.');
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    )};
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Again, what's the point of `function abc()` when the jQuery Validation plugin is being used?

Comment: Your solution still don't work, so I tried Sparky's solution. But still facing some issue. it would be pleasure if you help.