# ASP.NET MVC Application: Added jQuery event to submit button click and now jQuery Validate plugin no longer working.

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-validate

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application. I want to put the following jQuery code in my program to ensure that the image is displayed on the page prior to form submission:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function (e) {
    //If Corporation is selected as business type
    if ($('#businessStructure').val() == "Corporation") {
        //Checks CEO signature present
        if ($("#signImage").length == 0 || $("#signImage").attr("src") == "") {
            //block the user from submitting and check for signature
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Please sign and save your signature in the CEO signature pad");
            $("#ceoError").show();
        }
        else {
            //all good, an image exists
            $('form').submit();
        }
    }
});
```

This code (I'm guessing due to the e.preventDefault()) now completely ignores the jQuery Validate plugin that came with the MVC application. I, however, need to block the form submission if any textboxes are missing information (jQuery Validate) AND if the signature is missing (code above).

I understand why this is happening from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306495/jquery-validation-dont-work-on-submit-if-submit-has-some-code). How exactly do I go about fixing this code so that I am able to have jQuery Validate and the new code function on the submit button click?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you include the relevant script files needed for the unobutrusive jquery validation, when you submit the form, the validation will be executed and the validation messages will be displayed if any and the form **will not be submitted** to the server. So make sure you have the needed scripts included in your page

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

If you have script errors in the page, it might be the cause for your current scripts to not work as expected. I suggest you check your browsre console for any script errors in the page.

As i mentioned above,you can use both jQuery validate and your custom if condition. If you want to execute your custom if condition only if the form passes the validation, you can use the [`valid()`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) on the form to determine whether form has any validation errors.

Now

```
$('#submitButton').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var isvalid = $(this).closest("form").valid();
    if(isValid)
    {
       console.log('form validation passed');
       //do something custom
    }  
});
```